# Require shipping cost calculation in cart - but only if there are physical products in it

Tags: php, jquery, woocommerce

On my clients WooCommerce website we run a script that forces shipping-cost calculation on the cart-page:

```
add_action('wp_head','prevent_proceed_to_checkout');

function prevent_proceed_to_checkout() { 

echo '  <script>
            jQuery(function(){  
                jQuery(".woocommerce-cart .wc-proceed-to-checkout a.checkout-button").on("click",function(e){
                    var _this = this;
                    alert("Bitte berechne die Versandkosten!");
                    e.preventDefault();
                    jQuery(".shipping-calculator-form .button").on("click",function(){
                        jQuery(_this).off();
                    });
                 });
            });
        </script>';
}
```

I need to change this so that it is not executed if there are no physical products in the cart. I tried using javascript to check if .woocommerce-shipping-totals - class is in the dom, but I was not successful with the solution I came up with.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this now by adding an if-statement to the onclick-function that basically checks, if the ".woocommerce-shipping-totals"-class is beeing displayed on the page as soon as the checkout-button is clicked. Here is the code i added: (right before the alert)

```
var shipping = document.getElementsByClassName("woocommerce-shipping-totals").length;      
if (shipping > 0) {
```